# Why can this derived class be constructed with `{}` and not with `()` on C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

In this example, C++17 can construct a Derived class using the Base class's constructor using `{}`, but not `()`.
This also works on C++20 for GCC and Clang, but not for MSVC.
Why can I constuct the Derived class this way? Is it safe?

I have looked through the additions and changes in C++17 and can not find what changed to allow this.
It is very possible that I am blind.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(const int value) {
        std::cout << "Constructed with value: " << value << '\n';
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

int main(){
    // does compile on C++17 with MSVC
    // does not compile pre or post C++17 with MSVC
    // does compile on and post C++17 on GCC and Clang
    // does not compile pre C++17 with GCC and Glang
    Derived foo{ 42 };

    // does not compile on any C++ version with MSVC, GCC or Clang
    Derived bar(42);
}
```

Comment: Do you know why `{}` does not require the inherited class to do this?

Comment: What an Aggregate is has changed in every new version of C++ since and including C++11.  This is definitely coming into play, but I would suspect the code to work in C++17 mode, and I can't figure out why it isn't with GCC/Clang.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The question says it *does* compile in C++17 mode.

Comment: @NathanOliver is this really an Aggregate? cppreference says an an Aggregate is a type with `[...] no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) [...]` between c++17 and c++20.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh wow.  I forgot to comment the `Derived bar(42);` line out.  Silly me.  Looks like it might just be a MSVC issue then.

Comment: @florestan An inherited constructor is `using base_name::base_name`.  `Derived` doesn't have that, so it doesn't have any inherited constructors.  It also doesn't have any constructors defined, so it doesn't have a user-provided constructor, so it is an aggregate.

Comment: @NathanOliver Cool. Thanks for the clarification, this part of the standard is rather confusing to me :/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a quick rundown of the situation:

1. `Base` is implicitly convertible from an `int`.
2. `Base` is not an aggregate, since it has a user-provided constructor.
3. `Derived` is *not* convertible from an `int` (implicitly or otherwise), since base-class constructors are not inherited unless you explicitly inherit them (which you didn't).
4. `Derived` is not an aggregate due to having a base class... *in C++14*.
5. `Derived` *is* an aggregate in C++17, which allows aggregates to have base classes. `Derived` does not have any constructors provided by the user; again, `Base`'s constructor doesn't matter because it was not inherited.

Given these facts, what's happening is the following.

Attempting to use `{}` on a type will first (sort of) check to see if that type is an aggregate; if so, it will perform aggregate initialization using the values in the braced-init-list. Since whether `Derived` is an aggregate changed between C++14 and C++17, the validity of that initialization changed as well.

Per #4, `Derived` is not an aggregate in C++14. So list initialization rules will attempt to call a constructor that takes an `int`. Per #3, `Derived` has no such constructor. So `Derived foo{ 42 };` is il-formed in C++14.

Per #5, `Derived` is an aggregate in C++17. So list initialization rules will perform aggregate initialization. This is done by copy-initializing each subobject of the aggregate by the corresponding initializer in the braced-init-list. `Derived` has only one subobject, of type `Base`, and the braced-init-list only has one initializer: `42`. So it will perform copy-initialization of `Base` by the initializer `42`. That will attempt to perform implicit conversion from an `int` to `Base`, which is valid per #1.

So `Derived foo{ 42 };` is valid in C++17.

Visual Studio may not have implemented C++17's ruleset correctly.

Comment: C++ is such an expressive and friendly language.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I don't see the issue here. The only thing that is at all confusing is that the definition of aggregate changed from C++14 to C++17. And it changed in a way that made invalid code valid, so it was a safe change. The only reason this question exists is because MSVC seems to have a bug in its C++17 implementation.

Comment: The issue is that it takes an 18-line Stack Overflow answer to explain a code statement that's supposed to instantiate a simple class from an integer, and the explanation varies considerably across versions of the language in completely esoteric ways. It's ridiculous.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: "*instantiate a simple class from an integer*" A class that, on first inspection, does not look like it *can* be instantiated from an integer. That's where the complexity comes from.

Comment: I understand how C++ works here, but that doesn't it make any less terrible. I know where the complexity comes from, but there shouldn't be any for a task like this.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I don't understand the idea that this shouldn't involve complexity. It involves the usage of a constructor from a base class to initialize the derived class and a specialized form of initialization specifically for initializing individual subobjects of a class. That's going to involve complexity because it *is complicated*. That is the nature of the scenario. Most other languages wouldn't even allow you to do it, requiring that you can only initialize `Derived` by its explicitly provided constructors. C++ is more free, but that freedom requires complexity if you rely on it

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I feel personally attacked.

Comment: @NicolBolas We'll have to agree to disagree. C++ is like four separate languages at present, and whether or not we think this complexity is acceptable for such a scenario, the fact that there are completely different answers for C++ standards released over such a short period of time is absurd to me. I know I'm not the only one who think so. ‍♂️ You are of course free to disagree with that!

Comment: Which way of initializing a variable should be recommended/taught by default? `T val = x`, `T val(x)`, `T val{x}`, `T val = {x}`,  `auto val = T(x)` or `auto val = T{x}`. Each does a different thing. Depending on `T` and `x` some may not compile while some may compile and those who compile may do completely different things. And each standard version changes the rules and meanings of these. What should be the most trivial and common idiom (initializing a variable) has become a nightmare. You can fill a few SO detailed answers just to explain what each does depending on `T`, `x` and C++ version

Comment: @bolov: "*taught by default*" None. When dealing with a type more complex than fundamental types, users need to think in terms of what they are actually doing. If you mean to initialize an object with a list of values because it is a container, you use braces. If you mean to convert one object value to another (possibly of a different type), you use `= x`. If you mean to "call a constructor", you use parentheses. If you mean to initialize it with nothing, you use an empty `{}`.

Comment: With all due respect if you gather 5 C++ experts you will get 5 different opinions on what intialization to use. And I'm not the only one saying this.  I've heard Herb Sutter say something along these lines in his "measuring and reducing C++ accidental complexity" presentation.

Comment: @bolov: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here. Is initialization in C++ complicated? Yes, and there's no question of that. There are a *lot* of edge cases, and this is what makes a "by default" initialization form non-viable. But 80% of the time, what initialization is reasonable to use is pretty obvious. My overall point is that the example being asked here isn't problematic because it is *fundamentally* complicated. It was being described as a "simple class", and it is anything but that.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, my point is just that C++'s initialization is way more complicated than it needs be (mostly due to historical evolution of the language). I guess have a romantic and naive way of thinking about it - "if it were designed today it would have been much simpler". Anyway thank you for the great answer. Hope I didn't come across as aggressive or combative.